# Apache Velocity Web Browser Testing in Eclipse Java

Tags: java, html, email, velocity

Is there a way to test the string content that velocity returns in the eclipse browser, or why not, in the default browser of my pc. Because everytime i want to try how it looks the html mail i have to send it to my self.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by using a servlet and calling this servlet manually form the browser.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(/*VELOCITY STRING RESPONSE*/);
}
```